# Sorting an array of objects by 'desc' with numbers first

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by descending and beginning with number first, here's what I'm having:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'b' },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'c' }
];
_.orderBy(users, 'a', 'desc');
```

result:

```
0: Object {a: "b", user: "barney"}
1: Object {a: "c", user: "barney"}
2: Object {a: 48, user: "fred"}
3: Object {a: 40, user: "fred"}
```

expected result:

```
0: Object {a: 48, user: "fred"}
1: Object {a: 40, user: "fred"}
2: Object {a: "b", user: "barney"}
3: Object {a: "c", user: "barney"}
```

Comment: Why does the descending result have the strings ascending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide multiple sort keys ("iteratees") and the order for each key

```
_.orderBy(users, [x => isNaN(x.a), 'a'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

This will, however, sort the strings descending as well (that is, the result will be `48, 40, c, b`.

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 'a' },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 948 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 48 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': -480 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 'c' },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 548 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 4558 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 148 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 4834534 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 1 },
  { 'user': 'x',   'a': 'b' },
];

users = _.orderBy(users, [x => isNaN(x.a), 'a'], ['asc', 'desc']);
console.log(users)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, this is almost working, however it's sorting only by the first character of the number, for example: 91, 823, 7, 6422, 51, 409, 3234, 212, 1345. how do I fix it?

Comment: @Gustavo: fixed, have a look!

Comment: It fixed the numbers, but the sorting got back to normal (letters showing first than numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a check for type first and return the delta of the boolean values.

If not equal, check the type and return either the result of string comparison (ascending) or the delta of the numerical values (descending).

```js
var users = [{ 'user': 'fred', 'a': 48 }, { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'b' }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 40 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 0 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 0 }, { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'a' }, { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'd' }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 0 }, { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'c' }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 47 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'a': 46 }];

users.sort(({ a: a }, { a: b }) =>
    (typeof a === 'string') - (typeof b === 'string') ||
    (typeof a === 'string' ? a.localeCompare(b) : b - a));

console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @doodlemeister, now it checks the type and take the comparison accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If two elements which are going to be compared are letters, check by string comparison. If one of them is a letter, put it after the second always. If two are numbers just do a simple check.

```js
var users = [
   { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 48 },
   { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'b' },
   { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 40 },
   { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'c' }
];

users.sort((obj1, obj2) => {

  if(typeof obj1.a ==='string' && typeof obj2.a ==='string' ) {
     return obj1.a.localeCompare(obj2.a);
  }

  if(typeof obj1.a ==='string') {
     return 1;
  }
  
  return obj1.a - obj2.a;
});

console.log(users);
```

In your expected result your numbers are going in the descending order. For that you need just to replace `obj1.a - obj2.a` with `obj2.a - obj1.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the types to see if they match. If so, then sort based on what the types are. If not, then return `1` if they're strings, else `-1`. This will send the strings to the end.

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'b' },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'a': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'a': 'c' }
];

users.sort((a, b) => {
  const aTyp = typeof a.a;
  const isStr = aTyp == "string";
  
  if (aTyp == typeof b.a) {
    return isStr ? a.a.localeCompare(b.a) : b.a - a.a;
  }
  return isStr ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(users);
```